# How to create a tz1 address with a secret passphrase via command line?

Tags: tezos-client, wallets, secret

I'm trying to create a wallet with a secret passphrase(15 words), however I can't find any documentation.  Any way to do it via command line?

Yes, I know how to do it via Tezbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not supported by the command line client at the moment, but the [pytezos](https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos) library supports it, see [Key.generate](https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos/blob/master/pytezos/crypto.py#L174).

```
Generates new key
:param passphrase: optional password
:param curve: b'sp' for secp251k1, b'p2' for P256/secp256r1, b'ed' for Ed25519 (default)
:param strength: mnemonic strength, default is 128
:param language: mnemonic language, default is english
:param export: export as json file in the current folder, default is True :return: Key
```

Comment: Thanks!  does that also create encrypted keys?

Comment: I wrote the earliesr version of that lib and it did. I would assume it still does.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *"I know how to do it via Tezbox"*? Do you mean via UI or with the same library `eztz.js` by Stephen Andrews? This is the example code to create a new wallet using it:

```
<script src="eztz.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let mnemonic = eztz.crypto.generateMnemonic();
    let password = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,15);
    let wallet = eztz.crypto.generateKeys(mnemonic, password);
    console.log('address: '+wallet.pkh);
    console.log('private key: '+wallet.sk);
    console.log('mnemonic: '+mnemonic);
    console.log('password: '+password);
</script>
```